# How to collapse multiple rows of cell values in excel using powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

How can one collapse multiple rows of data such that it matches with its unique id. The data set is dynamically loaded from web. It is sorted by date so that each new entries update preceding entries.

Note:
I neither want to delete certain null values, nor ignore them by pivoting, because some of this null values are data yet to be filled.

I have a sample file with scattered rows of data on sheet 1. The solution I want to be provided is on sheet 2. How can one achieve this? This is the most complicated task. I will be happy if this challenge is resolved.

This is the link:
https://ibb.co/3kVkcBL

or somethiing similar

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DzOmjU0izheVfizGk7XZhPRCCb5VfPLO/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=100839365308659312055&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Posting in all capitals is the internet-equivalent of shouting/screaming, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you. As an aside, your question reads like a requirement, which is not how Stack Overflow works. We expect you to demonstrate genuine effort to solve your problem yourself and then ask a specific and focused question.

Comment: no one is going to request access to your google doc. Post the data in a public location for access

Comment: @horseyride Have updated the link so anyone can have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

*Read the code comments to better understand the algorithm*

***Edit:** to fix problem of missing grades*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"NAME", type text}, {"CLASS", type text}, 
        {"CACHEMISTRY", Int64.Type}, {"EXAM CHEMISTRY", Int64.Type}, 
        {"TOTALCHEM", Int64.Type}, {"GRADECHEM", type text}, {"CABIOLOGY", Int64.Type}, 
        {"EXAMBIOLOGY", Int64.Type}, {"TOTALBIOLOGY", Int64.Type}, {"GRADEBIOLOGY", type text}, 
        {"Date", type datetimezone}}),

//There some "string" nulls. Will replace them with real nulls so we can "fill up"
    replaceNulls = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","null",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")),

//Group by Name and ID
// then fill up all the columns and return the last row only
    group = Table.Group(replaceNulls,{"ID","NAME"},{
        {"newTable", each Table.Last(Table.FillDown(Table.FillUp(_,Table.ColumnNames(_)),Table.ColumnNames(_)))}
    }),

//Expand the results
    columnsToExpand = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(replaceNulls),2),
    #"Expanded newTable" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(group, "newTable",
        columnsToExpand,columnsToExpand),

//Set Data Types
// Note that Date column is typed as text
//    This is so it will display near properly in Excel (it will be missing the "T"
//    You may need to modify this depending on whether this is satisfactory or not
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded newTable",{
        {"CLASS", type text}, 
        {"CACHEMISTRY", Int64.Type}, {"EXAM CHEMISTRY", Int64.Type}, 
        {"TOTALCHEM", Int64.Type}, {"GRADECHEM", type text}, {"CABIOLOGY", Int64.Type}, 
        {"EXAMBIOLOGY", Int64.Type}, {"TOTALBIOLOGY", Int64.Type}, {"GRADEBIOLOGY", type text}, 
        {"Date", type text}})
    
in
    typeIt
```

***Note:**
There are some inconsistent differences. Some of them may be typos, others I'm not sure. These can be resolved, but you need to create consistent rules*

- There seem to be a mix of string "nulls" and actual *null* values. I converted them all to actual *null* values, but that could be easily changed.
- Ben Victor EXAMBIOLOGY is 40 on Sheet1 but 60 on Sheet2
- Ben Victor Datetime is `2022-03-16T15:14:00.000+01:00` and `2022-04-14T11:47:00.000+01:00` on sheet 1 but `2022-03-16T11:47:00.000+01:00` on sheet 2.  Which should it be?

***Original Table from Google Drive***
[image]

***Result after running above query***
*Note that the date is not formatted as you show, but that is a simple fix*

[image]

Comment: Sorry ,it was a typo.BEN victor CA=null EXAM BIOLOGY=60 on both sheets The dataset are dynamic each rows are coming with different time interval ,depending on the time it was sent.i was seeking for ways the last entry should be displayed without removing nulls because some nulls are values that are yet to be filled. –By the way this dataset provided is just a mock of the real set of data .The real data contain sensitive information to be disclose.

Comment: @val All you need to do then is change the `Table.Group` aggregation to return the last row of the grouped table rather than the first.  I edited my response to do that. How is it working for you?

Comment: The  Table.Group is returning error .I have copy and pasted the code u provided on the Advanced editor of powerquery. No way.I have even followed it step by step by inserting steps but no solution.How do i go about it?

Comment: This is the snapshot of the real data .The link is https://ibb.co/3kVkcBL

Comment: @valJust writing: "returning error" is not useful. What is the error? Is the Table.Group step the first step that shows the error? Also, I note from your screenshot that the column order in your screenshot is NOT the same as in your worksheet example. Which is correct? If the screenshot, the columnsToExpand step will also need to be changed. Also, your column names are not the same in the screenshot as in your worksheet example. You will have to edit the code to take that into account, wherever a column name is different.

Comment: i cant go beyond the group by. I am using the first workbook i shared via google drive. Am using excel 2016 version . This the struck..Group by Name and ID // then fill up all the columns and return the last row only group = Table.Group(replaceNulls,{"ID","NAME"},{ {"newTable", each Table.Last(Table.FillUp(,Table.ColumnNames()))} }), It is not working for me in my own powerquery window. Please paste the working logic .Thank you –

Comment: The group here is the name of your added steps?  I have grouped by the ID and 'NAME' n also fetch all rows of the table n have given it a new name ' newTable' so that my column headers are now ID,NAME newTable???  What am i missing? @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: This  is the link for effort made so far.....https://ibb.co/M1ysrwL

Comment: @val Must be a language problem. I don't understand how what you wrote is responsive to what I wrote.  I asked some questions about the error message and I see no response to that.  You write "*paste the working logic*" but I expect that is the code I already pasted (and the logic is within the code).  It works fine on the Google Drive sheet and I will add screen shots from that.

Comment: .Thank you so much.I 've fix the problem.Powerquery requires me to define once the Table.columnNames once,then i can use it.I dont why it was like that.

Comment: ,The challenge is still not totally resolved, as ID 1003 Ben Victor has  as no record  for column chemistry anymore?  see above what you uploaded? and ID 1005, FINA CHEMISTRY missing?

Comment: @val That was due to an error in my aggregation formula in Table.Group.  I have edited and fixed it now, and changed the screenshot to show the results.

Comment: ,thank you and appreciate your effort towards providing solution to this challenge. I will go through it and thereafter  check the green button..